# Which vehicle came with the most different engine cylinder configurations?

Tags: engine-theory, history

A question that cropped up in a discussion today...

Most vehicles sold come with one or two different engine cyinder configurations, for example and inline-4 and a V8. Quite a few have three, and a few have four (e.g. the Land Rover Defender, which was offered with an I4, I5, I6(South Africa only) and V8 at various times)

The question raised was - what model/type of car had the most configuration options from the factory? The best we have found so far is 5 (Toyota Land Cruiser J70 - I4,5,6, V6, V8)

It has to be a single model generation, to discount those vehicles that have been 'in production' for 30-40 years by sticking the same name onto successive different cars, but face-lifts do count...

Comment: What do you consider a variant? What counts as a single model (does a 1500, 2500, 3500 Silverado count as one vehicle or three separate)? My '06 1500 Silverado came with six different engines: 4.3L V6; 4.8L V8; 5.3L V8; 5.3L V8 Flex Fuel; 5.3L V8 Gas/Electric (hybrid); 6.0L V8. If you include the 2500 & 3500 series, there's two more engines: 6.6L V8 Turbo Diesel (Duramax); 8.1L V8. That's just in the US ... could be more if you include editions from other countries (do they have them in other countries?? dunno).

Comment: I'm counting all the variants on the same chassis/monocoque as one - so your example would be one vehicle, and two configurations - V6 and V8